# privateの変数、ｘとｙが意図したとおりに変化できない

Tags: c++

このプログラムを実行すると、decide_direction()内のｘとｙが意図したとおりに変化しません。教えてもらえませんか？
このコードを実行したときに出力されるｙの値を2, 4, 6, 8 ... としたいのですが、2, 2, 2, 2, ... と値が変わらないです。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
/*
 *棒倒し法
 */

class maze {
  int wall_info[77][77] = {{0}};
  int x, y;
public:
  maze();
  void make_wall();
  int decide_direction();
  int wall_check();
  void show();
};

maze::maze()
{
  //make wall
  for (y = 0; y <= 76; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x <= 76; x++) {
      if (y == 0 || x == 0 || y == 76 || x == 76) {
        wall_info[y][x] = 1;
      }if (y % 2 == 0 && x % 2 == 0) {
        wall_info[y][x] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  y = 2;
  x = 2;
}

void maze::make_wall()
{
  while (y < 76) {
    while (x < 76) {
      if (decide_direction() == 4) {
        wall_info[y - 1][x] = 1;
      }
      else if (decide_direction() == 3) {
        wall_info[y][x - 1] = 1;
      }
      else if (decide_direction() == 2) {
        wall_info[y + 1][x] = 1;
      }
      else {
        wall_info[y][x + 1] = 1;
      }
      x += 2;
    }
    y += 2;
    // std::cout << y << std::endl;
  }
}

int maze::decide_direction()
{
  int direction = 0;
  int check;

  std::cout << y << std::endl;

  if (y <=  2) {
    check = wall_check();
    if (wall_check() == -1) {
      direction = rand() % 3 + 1;
    }
    else {
      direction = rand() % 4 + 1;
    }
  }
  else {
    if (wall_check() == -1) {
      direction = rand() % 2 + 1;
    }
    else {
      direction = rand() % 3 + 1;
    }
  }

  return direction;
}

int maze::wall_check()
{
  if (wall_info[y][x - 1] == 1) {
    return -1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }
}

void maze::show()
{
  for (int i = 0; i <= 76; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 76; j++) {
      if (wall_info[i][j] == 1) {
        std::cout << "■ ";
      }
      else {
        std::cout << "□ ";
      }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
  maze maze;

  maze.make_wall();
  maze.show();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: 「変更できない」が第三者に何を伝えようとしているのかさっぱりわかりません。少なくともコード上で変更しようとしている痕跡が全くありません。回答者に何を望んでいるのか、もう一度質問内容を見直してください。

Comment: decide_direction()内にある、cout << y << endl; が 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ...となってしまうところを、2, 4, 6, 8, ... と make_wall()のwhileに合わせて変更させたいです。

Comment: 「変更できない(させたい)」ではなく「変数の値が意図した通りに変化しない」ではなないでしょうか？「変更できない」だと、変更するようなロジックを書けばいいだけでは？という(誤解した)印象を与えます。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。変更します。

Answer (score 4):

```
void maze::make_wall()
{
  while (y < 76) {
    while (x < 76) {
      // 省略
      x += 2;
    }
    y += 2;
    // std::cout << y << std::endl;
  }
}
```

このメソッドでは、二重ループで、まずxから計算しています。内側のループでxを計算している間、yの値は変わらないので、期待される出力は`2,2,2...4,4,4,...6,6,6...`です。しかし、実際には`2,2,2,...`になると思います。これは、最初の`y==2`の時に内側のルーフが終わった後、xを再初期化していないため、`y==4`以降、`x==76`のままで内側のループが実行されないためです。内側のループの直前でxを再初期化すればうまくいくはずです。

```
void maze::make_wall()
{
  while (y < 76) {
    x = 2; // ここを追加
    while (x < 76) {
```

---

ちなみに、ループの中で方向を決める部分ですが、

```
  if (decide_direction() == 4) {
    wall_info[y - 1][x] = 1;
  }
  else if (decide_direction() == 3) {
    wall_info[y][x - 1] = 1;
  }
  else if (decide_direction() == 2) {
    wall_info[y + 1][x] = 1;
  }
  else {
    wall_info[y][x + 1] = 1;
  }
```

一番最後の`else`の部分が実行される確率が、かなり高いと思います。`decide_direction()`を何度も呼び出していますが、返ってくる値はそのたびに違うからです。例えば、最初の`if`で`decide_direction()`が3を返すと、次の`else if`が実行され、そこで2が返ってくると、更にその次の`else if`が実行され、そこで4が返ってくると、1は一度も返ってきていないのに、1が返ってきた場合に当たる、最後の`else`が実行されてしまいます。ここは`switch`を使うのが良いでしょう。

```
switch (decide_direction()) {
case 4:
    wall_info[y - 1][x] = 1;
    break;
case 3:
    wall_info[y][x - 1] = 1;
    break;
case 2:
    wall_info[y + 1][x] = 1;
    break;
default:
    wall_info[y][x + 1] = 1;
    break;
}
```

Comment: できました。ありがとうございます。